# Password verifier

Tags: c++, passwords, c-strings

So I have tried this code many different ways and can not get it to run past the first if statement nor print out each issue.  My question is it it possible to do it like this without using functions? If so will you please help me fix my code so that it works or at least guide me in the right direction. I feel like this code is missing a key part or two and I can not wrap my mind around it.

**********Updated Version*******************************

(still wont work)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

//Create program that verifies that a password meets certain criteria.The 
//password must :

//-Be at least eight characters long
//- Contain an uppercase letter
//- Contain a lowercase letter
//- Contain a numeric digit

//Prompt the user to enter a password and then verify it.Your program should 
//list every issue the password has.

int main()
{
cout << "**************************************************** \n";
cout << "Your password must be characters long and containt: \n";
cout << "An uppercase letter. \n";
cout << "A lowercase letter. \n";
cout << "And a number. \n";
cout << "**************************************************** \n";
cout << "    \n";

const int size = 200;
char pass1[size], pass2[size];
const unsigned int password_length = 8U;
unsigned int length = 0;
bool has_lower_case_letter = false;
bool has_digit = false;
bool has_upper_case_letter = false;
char password[password_length + 1];

    cout << "Please enter a password: ";
        cin >> pass1;

while (length < password_length)
{

    if (!has_lower_case_letter)
    {
        static const char lower_case_letters[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        static const int letter_quantity = 
            sizeof(lower_case_letters) / sizeof(lower_case_letters[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < letter_quantity; ++i)
        {
            if (pass1[size] == lower_case_letters[i])
            {
                has_lower_case_letter = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!has_upper_case_letter)
    {
        static const char upper_case_letters[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        static const int letter_quantity =
            sizeof(upper_case_letters) / sizeof(upper_case_letters[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < letter_quantity; ++i)
        {
            if (pass1[size] == upper_case_letters[i])
            {
                has_upper_case_letter = true;

            }
        }
    }

    if (!has_upper_case_letter)
    {
        static const char digits[] = "0123456789";
        static const int digit_quantity =
            sizeof(digits) / sizeof(digits[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < digit_quantity; ++i)
        {
            if (pass1[size] == digits[i])
            {
                has_digit = true;

            }
        }
    }

    password[length] = pass1[size];
    ++length;
}

if (!has_digit)
    cout << "The password must contain a digit. \n";

if (!has_upper_case_letter)
    cout << "The password must include an uppercase letter. \n";

if (!has_lower_case_letter)
    cout << "The password must include a lowercase letter. \n";

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Off topic: "Your password must be characters long and containt:" missing how many characters long and contain picked up an extra t.

Comment: I'm confused.  Why do you use `std::string` for `password`, but character arrays for both `pass1` and `pass2`?  The `cin` will fill your array with as many characters as the User types (plus that pesky terminating nul character).  Try typing in 10 characters and see what happens.

Comment: Read the documentation for the `isupper`, `islower`, and `isdigit` functions. Note that the `while` loop does not re-ask for input. Once in, you're stuck in.

Comment: Your `isupper`, `islower` and `isdigit` are checking the slot in the array after the terminating nul.  They are not searching the entire character array.

Comment: Also, why are you using a `while` statement when the `pass1` and `pass2` are not changing in the loop?

Comment: Equality in an if statement uses `==`, not `=`. One `=` for assignment, two for comparison.

Comment: For `bool` variables, you don't need to compare to `true` or `false`.  You can use the `!` operator when comparing to `false`, e.g. `if (!has_digit)`

Answer (score 0):

You can't write your program without functions, as `main` is a function and you are using a function to get input from a user.

That said, yes, you can check a text string without using functions for searching.

```
const unsigned int password_length = 8U;
unsigned int length = 0;
bool has_lower_case_letter = false;
bool has_digit = false;
bool has_upper_case_letter = false;
char password[password_length + 1];
while (length < password_length)
{
  char c;
  cin >> c;
  if (!has_lower_case_letter)
  {
    static const char lower_case_letters[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    static const letter_quantity =
        sizeof(lower_case_letters) / sizeof(lower_case_letters[0]);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < letter_quantity; ++i)
    {
       if (c == lower_case_letters[i])
       {
          has_lower_case_letter = true;
          break;
       }
    }
  }
  //...
  password[length] = c;
  ++length;
}
```

The check for upper case letters and digits is left as an exercise for the poster.

Comment: Thank you! I really do appreciate you helping me out with this. Though i do have a question. for password_length = 8U; why is there a U after the 8?

Comment: The 'U' converts the *signed integer* number 8 to an *unsigned integer*.  This allows the constant to match the type.

Comment: I got it to work for a second and then it just stopped working on me and i can not figure out why.

Comment: Equality in an `if` statement uses `==`, not `=`.  One `=` for assignment, two for comparison.

Comment: now it will print all 3 bottom statements no matter what is entered

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  Watch values of variables as you step through the statements.  Follow the execution.  Determine what is happening and why it differs from your expectations.

Comment: To be honest I have no clue how to understand what its trying to tell me. It just repeats 'cannot find or open the PDB file' over and over again the exits the program.

Comment: alrite so I solved that and made it to where it downloads all the symbols and yet it still does not show me why it is not working. I am so confused,